# Обращение к данным внутри массива

Tags: php

есть массив:

```
$_DIR = [
    "mnt" => "/var/mnt",
    "backup_server" => "{$_DIR['mnt']}/{$_SERVER['ip']}",
    "share" => "{$_DIR['mnt']}/share"
];
```

И получается что при обращении к `$_DIR['mnt']` выдает ошибку.

```
 Undefined variable: _DIR
```

Как обратиться к элементам внутри массива?

Comment: есть предложение исправить вашем профиле слово приши т. к. считаю это опечаткой ...

Comment: @Leks, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

несколько странно пытаться обратиться к переменной во время ее объявления. Что, например, вы бы ожидаете от выражения `$i = $i + 5` ?

объявите этот путь `/var/mnt` константой, или вынесите в какой-то конфиг, а потом ее используйте.

```
define('MNT_DIR', '/var/mnt/');
$_DIR = [
     "mnt" => MNT_DIR,
     "backup_server" => MNT_DIR . $_SERVER['ip'],
     "share" => MNT_DIR . "share";
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вносите в массив `$_DIR` значения из массивов `$_DIR` и `$_SERVER`
Полагаю, что именно там нет массива `$_DIR` 
Сам параметр вызываете Вы верно.

Вот пример:

```php
$_DIR = array("mnt" => "123"); // Проверьте, есть ли у Вас такой массив
$_SERVER = array("ip" => "127.0.0.1");


$_DIR = [
    "mnt" => "/var/mnt",
    "backup_server" => "{$_DIR['mnt']}/{$_SERVER['ip']}", // Тут Вы вызываете параметр из массива $_DIR.
    "share" => "{$_DIR['mnt']}/share" // И тут
];

print_r($_DIR['mnt']);
print_r($_DIR['backup_server']);
print_r($_DIR['share']);
```

Результат:

```
/var/mnt
123/127.0.0.1
123/share
```

Answer (score 0):

Долго и нудно:

```
$_DIR["backup_server"] = "{$_DIR['mnt']}/{$_SERVER['ip']}";
$_DIR["share"] = "{$_DIR['mnt']}/share";
```